# Google Apps Script google.script.run.withSuccessHandler failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I have 2 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler calls that happen one after the other, and when I try to combine the two, it doesn't work. Here is the code that works, with all major things that are affected.

```
//These are in a javascript function which executes when a submit button is clicked.
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateOutput).processForm(frmData);
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnMessage).sendEmail(theData, titles);

//server functions
function processForm(theForm) {
  try{
    var fileBlob1 = theForm.resumeFile;

    var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById('My Folder ID');
    fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob1);

    return 'good';
  }catch(e) {

  }//End catch
}

function sendEmail(arr, titles) {
  try {
         //This function sends an email and edits a spreadsheet. Nothing is affected
       return 'Request Submitted';
  }
}
```

But when I try to combine the two, the program recognizes that the submit button has been clicked, but it doesn't move past the google.script.run.withSuccessHandler command.

```
//google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateOutput).processForm(frmData);
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnMessage).sendEmail(theData, titles, frmData);



function sendEmail(arr, titles, theForm) {
  try {

    //Uploads the files
    var fileBlob1 = theForm.resumeFile;

    var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById('My Folder ID');
    fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob1);
    var url1;
    //Contains the rest of the code for sending an email and editing a spreadsheet.


    return 'Request Submitted';
  }
}
```

This does not work. Does anyone know why this fails? The functions that are called when the first functions are successful both only display a popup telling the user that their response was submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Google documentation:

> A form element within the page is also legal as a parameter, but it must be the function’s only parameter.

You can not pass anything else with a form element, it must be the only parameter.

[Google Documentation - google.script.run.function(parameter)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myfunction-any-server-side-function)